# blue button appears as silver on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have this html code of a blue login button:

```
<div class="p12">
<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button loginButton">
</div>
```

and the style of it(css):

```
.loginButton {
background-color:#627aad;
border:1px solid #556A96;
width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

}

it should look like this:
[image]

and it looks like this on pc on every browser I tested(chrome, safari, IE...)
but I don't know for what reason when I open the page on iphone safari the color of the button changes to silver and it looks like this: [image]

Comment: Set `background` to `#627aad` as well, and set `border-radius` to something closer to your normal login like `4px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use this to your button element in the css

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iOS adds more default styles to buttons than desktop browsers.

You can reset these styles with the following lines:

```
.button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:none;
}
```